# How to skip **forward slash** char in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can anyone tell how to skip forward slash char in python?

I want to create a directory abc(17/12/18)
so I tried

```
import os
os.makedirs('abc(17\/12\/18)')
```

but the folder created was **abc(17\)**

Can anyone tell what am I missing?
I searched on Internet but was unsuccessful.

Comment: A Slash in a file or folder name is almost always a bad idea and with some os not even allowed (windows for example). A better seperator would be an underscore: abc(17_12_18)

Comment: Furthermore the function `os.mkdir` is what you would use to create a single directory. `os.makedirs` is the _Recursive directory creation function. Like mkdir(), but makes all intermediate-level directories needed to contain the leaf directory._

Answer (score 2):

You could do this. This will create a directory named `abc(17∕12∕18)`.

```py
>>> import os  
>>> os.makedirs('abc(17' + u'\u2215' + '12' + u'\u2215' + '18)')
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to escape forward slashes in python, only backslashes. The reason you cannot use that filename is that forward slashes are illegal in windows filenames. try this:

```
import os
os.makedirs('abc(17-12-18)')
```

Comment: But I want to store the date in that specific format. I cannot go for any other format.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows and Linux, `/` is not allowed in folder name.

More information here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31976060/3813027